# Different localhost ports causes failed Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, python, docker, localhost

I am trying to host a Docker javascript app (RocketChat) on localhost:3000, and refer to a python script that is listening to localhost:5000. Running the script I get the following response:

[Error] Origin localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (response, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:5000/response due to access control checks.

The request being executed is as follows:

```
    var data = [];
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if(input.value !== "" && input.value){
        data["Type A"] = input.value;
    }
    else {
        data["Type B"] = "not valid";
    }
    client.open("POST", "http://localhost:5000/response", true);
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    client.withCredentials = false;
    client.send(data);
```

How would one edit local host to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin? All of the answers I could find referred to editing Node.js, which I do not have.

Comment: so, you want to know how to enable CORS in python? or is it in Docker? the latter, a google search for enable cors docker results in many links i

Comment: It's in Meteor JS specifically.

Comment: Your have to set CORS headers to allow the access, or you configure the webserver to serve the webapps as subfolders on the same host and port.

Comment: If you're using MeteorJS to serve your application, you can set like so `WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use((req, res, next) =>{res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); return next();});`.